# Python independent linear regression for several categories

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have to predict number of packets in my network traffic for each IP address independently. I have 8 IP adressess in my dataset, timewindow, isSending flag, weekday (X) and number of packets (Y).
I prepared one-hot encoding for every columns. 
My aim is to make traffic prediction for given vector: IP, day, timewindow, isSending.

I tried MLPRegressor treating whole dataset as one. It's giving a false output now because it treats whole data as one 'class'. I would like to prepare line regression for each ip address separately, but i have such a big dataset that it is impossible to fit model separately on my own.

Example of row from my dataset :
0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;9823
Contains 1 on possitions corresponding source IP, timewindow id, day.
It's a dataset just for test with only several timewindows and 1 day. At the end is number of packets that flowed from IP in certain timewindow and day.

My outputs are tottaly unacceptable, for example i expect 3 and have -134

Comment: What *exactly* is your **question**?

Comment: This question is more suitable at Cross Validated, you will find statistics and ML related answers.

Comment: You can also check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895000/regression-by-group-in-python-pandas

Comment: @Prerit think it'll help me to solve problem, thx

Comment: @OjciecDwa glad I could help!